# Sell software that uses libraries licensed under Apache Licence 2.0

Tags: apache-2.0, commercial

I didn't find any definite answers on the web so I'm asking for a definite answer to the question:

Am I allowed to sell software that was written completely by myself except for the ZXing library (licensed under Apache License 2.0) and the Material Icon Collection by Google (also licensed under Apache License 2.0) as long as I include attribution to the authors of both packages?

If not, what do I have to do to be allowed to sell my software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to sell your software that is based on other software licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Apache has a good abstract for the license here: http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN

Comment: Thank you! But I just noticed that Material Icons are now licensed under Creative Commons Attribution 4.0. Is there any difference in what I have to do to legaly use the material in my commercial product?

Comment: For that you will just have to credit the authors. Creative Commons explains it pretty good on their site: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

Comment: @theCNG27 The material icons license is tricky. I just checked their GitHub page, and they put in a pull request that puts the license under Apache 2.0

Comment: Well if it's tricky I could also make my own icons because I only need a few. On the material icons page they say they are licensed under Apache 2.0 on the GitHub page they said CC-BY. I didn't notice that they changed to Apache 2.0 again... How can I be sure about that?